# How do I examine and reduce what "About This Mac" categorizes as "System" disk use?

Tags: hard-drive, storage

In "About This Mac" my Storage shows a System disk use of 419 GB. Since my storage is a bit tight and I'm gearing up to update to Catalina (from 10.14.6), I'd like to clear as much disk space as I can, and this huge chunk attributed to "System" seems a good place to start.

What is in System? How do I examine the details of what's there? How can I delete (safely) some of the things there consuming disk space?

---

FWIW, I have a lot of local Dropbox files, use Google Drive, have a disk image on my drive, and have a bunch of Homebrew installed tools (in case any of these could wind up categorized as "System").

Comment: Re *What is in System? How do I examine the details of what's there?*, there are some good questions https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/5353?lq=1 here. Also, for *How can I delete (safely) some of the things there consuming disk space?*, I think individual questions would be preferable, like *What does cache folder contain?* etc..

Answer (score -1):

You should get a copy of [DaiseyDisk](https://daisydiskapp.com) or [GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net). These apps will produce a mapping of your hard drive so you can check what is taking up so much space.

Comment: Those don't show what's in "System". The word "System", for example, seems to mean something different in DaiseyDisk (only 9.5 GB vs the 419 GB shown in About This Mac).

Comment: i think Daisey Disk is telling you that the System is really 9.5 GB and other files and folders compose the other 409 GB's.  You should look for any huge folders that could account for that.  My Library folder was considered part of my system by my Mac but not by DaiseyDisk.  My Library folder was 100 GB!